# How to make custom directive in Vue.js 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

I am following the guide of [Custom Directive](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-directives.html#overview) to create a custom directive in Vue.js 3.
I made a directive to change background of an element.

`Home.vue` includes usage of the custom directive and `main.js` includes the custom direcive definition.

"Home.vue"

```
<template>
    <p v-highlight="yellow">Home</p>
</template>
```

"main.js"

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
const app = createApp(App)

app.mount('#app');
app.directive("highlight",{
    beforeMount(el, binding){
        el.style.background = binding.value
    }
});
```

But I get the following error in console:

> "Cannot read property 'created' of undefined"

Does anyone help me?

Comment: "it didn't work" isn't helpful. Did you get an error? Did something unexpected happen? Did nothing happen? why are you calling `createApp` twice?

Comment: I got error like "Cannot read property 'created' of undefined" in console.
And nothing is displayed. 
createApp is missing, I editted my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply change the order of mount/directive

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
const app = createApp(App)

app.directive("highlight",{
    beforeMount(el, binding){
        el.style.background = binding.value
    }
});
app.mount('#app');
```

or you can do

```
app.directive("highlight",{
    beforeMount(el, binding){
        el.style.background = binding.value
    }
}).mount('#app');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!!